# EXECUTE or sp_executesql commands in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

What is the alternative of [SQL Execute Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-execute-with-a-character-string) in Kusto for running dynamic Kusto commands?

```
let query = 'MyTableX | where ColumnA == \'some-string\'';
EXECUTE ['query']
```

Answer (score 2):

At this point of time - such functionality is not available.
Please submit user-voice item at http://aka.ms/adx.uservoice